# How to make a club more inclusive?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/6277/82), I mentioned that asking a question along the lines of

> How to make a club more inclusive?

Would be downvoted and closed as too broad. Am I right?

My reasoning goes that it would be hard to find a "best" answer as a lot of answers might have good points in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that would be too broad. It's impossible to understand from such a question where the starting point of a club is, and what improvements could be made.

In your existing questions, you have done a good job of separating elements of [sexism](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexism) and [gender](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) that can be addressed and answered in manageable ways in StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Need more info YES off topic if edited NO

Although the question may be get opinion based answers it is:

1.) Clearly about marital arts or management of.

2.) It is a question that will probably be askes again by another user.

3.) "Best" answer is subjective although the top answer may not be the best anser (happens by the way) doesn't mean it is not good it is clearly a well recived answer.

4.) How as teachers or instructors are we to grow on here if we can not ask questions based on teaching or improving our schools?

5.) When all else fails trust, I think that posting the question to the community is the best way to identify what we as a hope find off topic, I agree with discussions about questions when they have been marked off topic and you disagree with the vote.

In general the question is missing information like how you want to make it exclusive so I think it would/should be flag in one way or another.

Comment: I think the topic is fine but the question is too broad. Were I to break it down in more answerable chunks, those would be good questions.

Comment: Agreed, think we should make sure they are able to edit these types of questions and they aren't completely closed

Comment: Could not agree more.